# standardize of data in sas

Tags: statistics, sas

**Objective is to interpolate and extrapolate date , endtime and likes **

I have data like this

```
Date        end time         likes 
08/11/2013  3.36 pm     36439569
09/11/2013  4.00pm      36439669
10/11/2013  3.10pm      36439700
11/11/2013  4.15pm      36439713
12/11/2013  12.00pm     36439719
14/11/2013  2.00pm      36439730
15/11/2013  4.10pm      36439800
16/11/2013  9.00pm      36439881
```

we are collected data from online. each day at Irregular time intervals the data is collected at each day. for example i collected data(total number of cumulative likes) for 08/11/2013 at time intervals 9 am  10 am  5 pm ,...note that the time is irregular. 
 now i need to standardize this  time intervals at day level and also likes. my final output looks like this

```
Final Output                
08/11/2013  3.00AM  09/11/2013  3.00AM  100
09/11/2013  3.00AM  10/11/2013  3.00AM  20
10/11/2013  3.00AM  11/11/2013  3.00AM  644
11/11/2013  3.00AM  12/11/2013  3.00AM  21
12/11/2013  3.00AM  13/11/2013  3.00AM  58
13/11/2013  3.00AM  14/11/2013  3.00AM  2
14/11/2013  3.00AM  15/11/2013  3.00AM  125
15/11/2013  3.00AM  16/11/2013  3.00AM  35
```

Please help me to get this output

thanks

Comment: Look at the `intnx` function. You can use that to fix the end time to one time each day and then take differences.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SAS/ETS licenced then check out PROC EXPAND, which can be used for interpolation and extrapolation.
As @Yick hinted, you're more likely to get a full answer on here if you try to solve the problem yourself first